# Python handling the name error exception

Tags: python, exception, nameerror

I wrote a small code and tried to handle the name error exception.
I want to print a custom message even if there is an exception, but it is showing the complete the trace back.

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt

import logging

def equaldigits(a, b):
    logging.basicConfig(filename='run.log',level=logging.INFO)
    try:
      c = a - b
      logging.info('%s is the difference between both the digits', str(c))
      print c
      return c
    except NameError as e:
      c = 'Unable to successfully complete execution'
      logging.info(c)
      print c
      #return c

def main():
  print '\n1st call'
  equaldigits(10, 10)
  print '\n2nd call'
  equaldigits(1, 0)
  print '\nException call'
  equaldigits(a, 0)

# Standard boilerplate to call the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

This is the console output

```
1st call
0

2nd call
1

Exception call
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sut.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "./sut.py", line 24, in main
    equaldigits(a, 0)
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your attempt to catch an exception, you wrote `equaldigits(a, 0)`. The interpreter sees the `a` and thinks it is a variable that isn't there, thus throwing the uncaught exception. In order to test your try/catch, you need to pass the *letter* a, like so

```
equaldigits('a', 0)
            ^ ^ note the quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't happening within your `equaldigits` function where you have your logging information.

Its happening in your `main` function when the interpreter tries to pass the value of `a` to `equaldigits`. The variable `a` doesn't exist within the local scope of `main`, thus Python tries to find a global variable named `a`. Since it doesn't see one, it throws a `NameError`.

Comment: I am trying to test it with passing an alphabet, a is not a variable to define in this case. I just want to catch the exception when I pass an alphabet and do the subtraction. How should I do it?

Comment: When you say 'alphabet' do you mean a `str`? If so, then you are testing for the wrong error. A `NameError` is thrown when Python cannot resolve a variable. You would want to test for `TypeError` in your code. This error is thrown when you try to subtract two incompatible types.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I got it using the TypeError and also I needed to put the variable in quotes, small mistake. May be lost in new python style of doing things.

Comment: What the quotes do it make `a` into a string instead of a variable name. Thats why you r code was able to get into `equaldecimals`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by the fact that a is not defined when you call equaldigits, the execution doesn't get to the try/except clause inside the function.

when you change

```
a - b
```

to

```
a - d
```

inside the function you'll see that your try/except works fine